# Linear Regression Channel Plotting Option

Tags: pine-script

I am using "Linear Regression Channel" as one of my overlays, and I am using all the overlays integrated in one single pine-script. Now, I need to add an option in the "Linear Regression Channel" to plot it or not, so the I can turn it on and off as I require. I think it can be done using `input.bool` function in pine-script. But I can't figure out on which line I should add the option. My code is as follows -

```
//Linear Regression Channel

src = input(defval = close, title = "Source")
len = input.int(defval = 100, title = "Length", minval = 10)
devlen = input.float(defval = 2., title = "Deviation", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)
lrcPlot = input.bool(title = "Plot LRC?", defval=false)
extendit = input(defval = true, title = "Extend Lines")
showfibo = input(defval = false, title = "Show Fibonacci Levels")
showbroken = input(defval = false, title = "Show Broken Channel", inline = "brk")
brokencol = input(defval = color.blue, title = "", inline = "brk")
upcol = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Up/Down Trend Colors", inline = "trcols")
dncol = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "trcols")
widt = input(defval = 1, title = "Line Width")

var fibo_ratios = array.new_float(0)
var colors = array.new_color(2)
if barstate.isfirst
    array.unshift(colors, upcol)
    array.unshift(colors, dncol)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.236)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.382)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.618)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.786)


get_channel(src, len)=>
    mid = math.sum(src, len) / len
    slope = ta.linreg(src, len, 0) - ta.linreg(src, len, 1)
    intercept  = mid - slope * math.floor(len / 2) + ((1 - (len % 2)) / 2) * slope
    endy = intercept  + slope * (len - 1) 
    dev = 0.0
    for x = 0 to len - 1
        dev := dev + math.pow(src[x] - (slope * (len - x) + intercept), 2)
    dev := math.sqrt(dev/len)
    [intercept, endy, dev, slope]

[y1_, y2_, dev, slope] = get_channel(src, len)

outofchannel = (slope > 0 and close < y2_ - dev * devlen) ? 0 : (slope < 0 and close > y2_ + dev * devlen) ? 2 : -1

var reglines = array.new_line(3)
var fibolines = array.new_line(4)
for x = 0 to 2
    if not showbroken or outofchannel != x or nz(outofchannel[1], -1) != -1
        line.delete(array.get(reglines, x))
    else
        line.set_color(array.get(reglines, x), color = brokencol)
        line.set_width(array.get(reglines, x), width = 2)
        line.set_style(array.get(reglines, x), style = line.style_dotted)
        line.set_extend(array.get(reglines, x), extend = extend.none)
    
    array.set(reglines, x, 
              line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                       y1 = y1_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1), 
                       x2 = bar_index, 
                       y2 = y2_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1),
                       color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                       style =  x % 2 == 1 ? line.style_solid : line.style_dashed,
                       width = widt,
                       extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
if showfibo
    for x = 0 to 3
        line.delete(array.get(fibolines, x))
        array.set(fibolines, x, 
                  line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                           y1 = y1_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), 
                           x2 = bar_index, 
                           y2 = y2_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x),
                           color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                           style =  line.style_dotted,
                           width = widt,
                           extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
    
var label sidelab = label.new(x = bar_index - (len - 1), y = y1_, text = "S",  size = size.large)
txt = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? "⇑" : "⇗" : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? "⇓" : "⇘" : "⇒"
stl = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_upper_right : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? label.style_label_down :  label.style_label_lower_right : label.style_label_right
label.set_style(sidelab, stl)
label.set_text(sidelab, txt)
label.set_x(sidelab, bar_index - (len - 1))
label.set_y(sidelab, slope > 0 ? y1_ - dev * devlen : slope < 0 ? y1_ + dev * devlen : y1_)
label.set_color(sidelab, slope > 0 ? upcol : slope < 0 ? dncol : color.blue)

alertcondition(outofchannel, title='Channel Broken', message='Channel Broken')

// direction
trendisup = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope > 0
trendisdown = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope < 0
alertcondition(trendisup, title='Up trend', message='Up trend')
alertcondition(trendisdown, title='Down trend', message='Down trend')
```

Please help me to resolve this. Thanks for your time. Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the input statement like plotregression=input.bool(true,"Plot Regression") and then check the input variable before plotting the lines. Example below

```
//@version=5
//Linear Regression Channel
indicator("test",overlay=true)
src = input(defval = close, title = "Source")
len = input.int(defval = 100, title = "Length", minval = 10)
devlen = input.float(defval = 2., title = "Deviation", minval = 0.1, step = 0.1)
lrcPlot = input.bool(title = "Plot LRC?", defval=false)
extendit = input(defval = true, title = "Extend Lines")
showfibo = input(defval = false, title = "Show Fibonacci Levels")
showbroken = input(defval = false, title = "Show Broken Channel", inline = "brk")
brokencol = input(defval = color.blue, title = "", inline = "brk")
upcol = input(defval = color.lime, title = "Up/Down Trend Colors", inline = "trcols")
dncol = input(defval = color.red, title = "", inline = "trcols")
widt = input(defval = 1, title = "Line Width")
plotregression=input.bool(true,"Plot Regression")

var fibo_ratios = array.new_float(0)
var colors = array.new_color(2)
if barstate.isfirst
    array.unshift(colors, upcol)
    array.unshift(colors, dncol)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.236)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.382)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.618)
    array.push(fibo_ratios, 0.786)


get_channel(src, len)=>
    mid = math.sum(src, len) / len
    slope = ta.linreg(src, len, 0) - ta.linreg(src, len, 1)
    intercept  = mid - slope * math.floor(len / 2) + ((1 - (len % 2)) / 2) * slope
    endy = intercept  + slope * (len - 1) 
    dev = 0.0
    for x = 0 to len - 1
        dev := dev + math.pow(src[x] - (slope * (len - x) + intercept), 2)
    dev := math.sqrt(dev/len)
    [intercept, endy, dev, slope]

[y1_, y2_, dev, slope] = get_channel(src, len)

outofchannel = (slope > 0 and close < y2_ - dev * devlen) ? 0 : (slope < 0 and close > y2_ + dev * devlen) ? 2 : -1

var reglines = array.new_line(3)
var fibolines = array.new_line(4)
for x = 0 to 2
    if plotregression
        if not showbroken or outofchannel != x or nz(outofchannel[1], -1) != -1
            line.delete(array.get(reglines, x))
        else
            line.set_color(array.get(reglines, x), color = brokencol)
            line.set_width(array.get(reglines, x), width = 2)
            line.set_style(array.get(reglines, x), style = line.style_dotted)
            line.set_extend(array.get(reglines, x), extend = extend.none)
        
        array.set(reglines, x, 
                  line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                           y1 = y1_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1), 
                           x2 = bar_index, 
                           y2 = y2_ + dev * devlen * (x - 1),
                           color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                           style =  x % 2 == 1 ? line.style_solid : line.style_dashed,
                           width = widt,
                           extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
if showfibo
    for x = 0 to 3
        line.delete(array.get(fibolines, x))
        array.set(fibolines, x, 
                  line.new(x1 = bar_index - (len - 1), 
                           y1 = y1_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x), 
                           x2 = bar_index, 
                           y2 = y2_ - dev * devlen + dev * devlen * 2 * array.get(fibo_ratios, x),
                           color = array.get(colors, math.round(math.max(math.sign(slope), 0))),
                           style =  line.style_dotted,
                           width = widt,
                           extend = extendit ? extend.right : extend.none))
    
var label sidelab = label.new(x = bar_index - (len - 1), y = y1_, text = "S",  size = size.large)
txt = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? "⇑" : "⇗" : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? "⇓" : "⇘" : "⇒"
stl = slope > 0 ? slope > slope[1] ? label.style_label_up : label.style_label_upper_right : slope < 0 ? slope < slope[1] ? label.style_label_down :  label.style_label_lower_right : label.style_label_right
label.set_style(sidelab, stl)
label.set_text(sidelab, txt)
label.set_x(sidelab, bar_index - (len - 1))
label.set_y(sidelab, slope > 0 ? y1_ - dev * devlen : slope < 0 ? y1_ + dev * devlen : y1_)
label.set_color(sidelab, slope > 0 ? upcol : slope < 0 ? dncol : color.blue)

alertcondition(outofchannel, title='Channel Broken', message='Channel Broken')

// direction
trendisup = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope > 0
trendisdown = math.sign(slope) != math.sign(slope[1]) and slope < 0
alertcondition(trendisup, title='Up trend', message='Up trend')
alertcondition(trendisdown, title='Down trend', message='Down trend')
```

Comment: You are my savior. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
for x = 0 to 2
    if plotregression
```

The if before the for

```
if plotregression
    for x = 0 to 2
```